# How to push this six-line code in to list comprehension in Python

Tags: python

It is a small *binary clock* representation code. There isn't much to explain about the code itself; the given number *num* is factorized by the powers of two (max=2^5) in the shortest divisor count possible (without repetition).
Since it is quite small, I was wondering if it could be made in to a list comprehension or a generator expression; take a look:

```
num = 39

div = [2**x for x in xrange(5,-1,-1)]
for d in div:
    if num/d:
        num = num - ((num/d) * d)
        print d,
```

prints:

```
32 4 2 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use (for six bits):

```
 [ (1 << b) for b in range (5, -1, -1) if num & (1 << b) ]
```

---

As you are talking about a "binary clock" I wonder if you really need the powers. For example if `X` is ON and `blank` is OFF, I would do:

```
def binaryDisplay (num, bits):
    return ' '.join ('X' if num & (1 << b) else ' ' for b in range (bits - 1, -1, -1) )

for minute in range (60):
    print (minute, binaryDisplay (minute, 6) )
```

---

Putting everything together, you can build your binary clock like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def binaryDisplay (num, bits):
    return ' '.join ('X' if num & (1 << b) else ' ' for b in range (bits - 1, -1, -1) )

now = datetime.now ().time ()
h, m, s = now.hour, now.minute, now.second
print (' : '.join ( (binaryDisplay (h, 5), binaryDisplay (m, 6), binaryDisplay (s, 6) ) ) )
```

(Displays current time)

Comment: A wonderful suggestion indeed! I was wondering how this bitwise `&` operator was put to use in `num & (1 << b`

Comment: `x & (1 << b)` simply checks whether bit `b` is set in integer `x`. Returns zero if not set, and non-zero if set.

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat mystical solution

```
def f(num):
    return [2**(num.bit_length() - i - 1) for i, digit in enumerate(bin(num)[2:]) if digit == "1"]
```

If you don't mind that the order of the powers are reversed you can do

```
def f(num):
    return [2**i for i, digit in enumerate(reversed(bin(num)[2:])) if digit == "1"]
```

Comment: Avoid the fiddly part with `enumerate(reversed(bin(num)[2:]))` and then reverse again afterwards?

Comment: @SteveJessop I initially did it this way but then the returned list has to be reversed too, to get the same output like OP.

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting to use string operations instead of bit-test or is this answer meant to be esoteric?

Comment: @Hyperboreus You are definitely right that your solution is preferable. Just wanted to show a different approach.